# re3-tensorflow or SiamMask on Coral

Tags: tensorflow, tpu, tensorflow-lite, google-coral, siamese-network

Would it be possible to run Re3: Real-Time Recurrent Regression Networks for Visual Tracking of Generic Objects (https://github.com/danielgordon10/re3-tensorflow) or SiamMask (https://github.com/foolwood/SiamMask) on google Coral edgeTPU?

I have re3 and SiamMask running on my PC but would love to try it on the EdgeTPU.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell since I don't know much about those architecture, I suggest trying it first and give details info if something fails. In that case there are some type of info that you can share which would help in debugging. Any how, you can check whether if those models are compatible using [this table](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/#supported-operations).

FYI, if you are interested in object tracking with coral's stack, perhaps you can also try [this example](https://github.com/google/automl-video-ondevice#for-coral-device) from the tensorflow team? :)

Comment: I will try getting SiamMask to run off mobilenet and follow up. It's quite an operation to make it work, so I was wondering if anyone had done it before.
FYI the example you linked to is for image classification, but not for tracking as far as I can tell. 
Thanks for the reply, I will follow up.

Comment: Hi again! Actually, this example uses the object detection api to get locations and bounding boxes of object: https://github.com/google/automl-video-ondevice/blob/master/examples/coral_camera_demo.py

The tracking is done after the inference results from the model: https://github.com/google/automl-video-ondevice/blob/master/automl_video_ondevice/object_tracking/tflite_object_detection.py#L132

Comment: just saw that! thanks for the info.
On my development machine I get awesome performance (in terms of quality of tracking) out of the SiamMask system - I will see if I can get similar performance from the automl.

Comment: I'm checking out SiamMask, looks like it'll be different from what he above repo provides tho

Comment: When I try to run the object tracker in the coral_camera_demo.py example (--use_tracker True), I get the following error:
RuntimeError: The basic tracker is not publicly available yet, please reach out to repo maintainers for early access. If this error persists, it may mean your CPU architecture is not yet supported.

Comment: Yikes! Didn't realized that, I guess you can drop them a line as a gh issue?

Comment: I did, will see if I get a response

Comment: A few months later, and I never got a response and I still get the same "not publicly available yet" issue even after re-cloning.